# How to communicate I2c device connected to Arduino to Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: arduino, win-universal-app, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I have a UWP app which will display values of sensors connected to Arduino which will be connected to that UWP app. I have a I2C device connected to that Arduino. I want to communicate to that I2C device from my UWP application. But, I can't find a way to do that. Can Someone can help me with that.

Comment: Maybe use the [arduino.stackexchange.com](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/)... And concerning your question: Talk to the Arduino via serial and calculate the I2C commands on the Arduino and send them to your I2C device.

Comment: ahh.. via SERIAL. hmmm. thanks.

Comment: actually i was thinking of FIRMATA. thats what its for. isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a technology called [Windows Remote Arduino](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/WRA.htm) that allows you to control Arduino microcontroller connected to your Windows 10 UWP App. It uses FIRMATA protocol underneath, and I believe it allows you to control I2C sensors as well. If not, you can tweak the source code, because both FIRMATA implementation and Windows Remote Arduino are open source.